# No module named 'bayesian_bandit'

Tags: python-3.x

I am not able to find this library. Can someone help?

```
Error: No module named 'bayesian_bandit'
```

Where can I find this library? I downloaded all possible ones on PyPi but none of them is the right one.

Comment: can you paste the whole traceback? which module's requirement is that

Comment: @Atreyagaurav I am going over this script https://github.com/lazyprogrammer/machine_learning_examples/blob/master/ab_testing/convergence.py. In that, you will see hopefully more information so that you can guide which library I need to Pip install. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/lazyprogrammer/machine_learning_examples/tree/master/ab_testing, you should have looked at his whole project. the bayesian_bandit is his own module, so you have to copy that code, you can't just import other's code which isn't in pip.